# how to call category class method from another class

Tags: iphone, ipad

How to call category class method from another class

```
        @interface Event()
        {
         NSDictionary *e_Dict;
        NSString *e_String;
        }
        
     -(NSDictionary *)CheckEvent:(NSString *)string;
        @end
        
        @implementation Event
        
     -(NSDictionary *)CheckEvent:(NSString *)string{
       ......
.....................    
    return t_Dict; 
    
        }
```

I created new class which is UnitTesting

## import the class #import "Event.h"

```
-(void)testCheckEventNilDictionary {

Event *evt = [[Event alloc]init];
NSDictionary *t_Dictionary;

t_Dictionary = [evt CheckEvent:@"string"];


}
```

But for me i am unable to include CheckEvent method

```
[evt CheckEvent:@""]
```

Please any one let me know what i did wrong?

@All thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error message received?

Comment: 1) you should share the actual compiler error or warning or run-time failure, and specify what it is 2) You should read up on proper Objective-C naming conventions, trying to read your code is difficult due to you rejecting the community's standards. These two things will increase other people's ability to help answer your question.

Comment: Error messge :No visible @interface for Event declare the selector CheckEvent.,

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have to declare the method in the header file of categoryClass

i.e in categoryClass.h declare

```
-(NSDictionary *)CheckEvent:(NSString *)string;
```

Comment: No its not declared in the .h  But it declared in CategoryClass () i.e.,  @interface Event()  for my knowledge it need to access that method method which are declared inside CategoryClass () i.e, Event()

Comment: Error messge :No visible @interface for Event declare the selector CheckEvent.,

Comment: OK.As far as i see you have created an 'extension' not category.If you have defined it within .m file's interface, it cannot be accessed by any other class.

Comment: Thanks for your information!  Event its @Interface Event() Extension Which declared the methods in the extension do i able to access this methods without declaring into header file

Comment: Yes you can but you might receive a warning as accessing the private methods of a class from other always does

Comment: how can i receive method with out declaring in header file!  currently i am getting the error! warning is exceptional !!!

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge.

If you write the category inside the `.m` file and importing the .h file, you can't access it from other classes.

As a solution:

- You need to declare your category in .h file.
- In your class import your .m file (It's not a good thing)